# Kubernetes version upgraded, but kubectl showing different versions

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I just upgraded kubernetes cluster, but kubectl is very inconsistent in showing me the version. How can I verify this. Any source of truth?

```
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 k8s-test]$ kubectl  version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.3", GitCommit:"5e53fd6bc17c0dec8434817e69b04a25d8ae0ff0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-06T01:44:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.3", GitCommit:"5e53fd6bc17c0dec8434817e69b04a25d8ae0ff0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-06T01:36:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}


[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 k8s-test]$ kubectl  get nodes
NAME        STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
wp-np3-0b   Ready    worker   55d    v1.14.1
wp-np3-0f   Ready    worker   55d    v1.14.1
wp-np3-45   Ready    master   104d   v1.13.5
wp-np3-46   Ready    worker   104d   v1.13.5
wp-np3-47   Ready    worker   104d   v1.13.5
wp-np3-48   Ready    worker   43d    v1.14.1
wp-np3-49   Ready    worker   95d    v1.13.5
wp-np3-76   Ready    worker   55d    v1.14.1
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 k8s-test]$
```

Answer (score 3):

IIRC: `kubectl version` is telling you what version the APIServer is at (1.14.3). `kubectl get nodes` is telling you what version the `kubelet` is on those nodes.

Comment: So my cluster upgrade just upgraded the API server? and left Kubelets without upgrade?

Comment: How did you upgrade the cluster?

Comment: Never heard of / used it. `kubeadm` is the defacto tool for installing / upgrading k8s.